# How to combine different Likert variables into one new variable in R?

Tags: r, likert

I'm a beginner in R and have a question about combining different variables into one new variable.

My surv mey measures for example the construct *working overtime* by means of three variables (all measured on a 5-point Likert scale). These questions measure all different aspects of the construct. I would like to compute these three variables into one new mean variable in R. How can I do this? With the mutate function? I tried this, but I am not sure if it is right:

```
mutate(df, Working.Overtime = Q1, Q2, Q3)
```

I hope it's clear enough and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is not really an R question, but rather a scientific / measurement theory question.

Comment: What do you mean combine? Add them up?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    unite(Working.Overtime, Q1, Q2, Q3)
```

---

If we need the `mean`, use `rowMeans`

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(Mean = rowMeans(select(., Q1, Q2, Q3), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun, but then I get the answers of Q1,Q2 and Q3 in one column seperated by a comma. I would like to compute the variables into one mean variable, I edit my question so it is hopefully more clear. Do you know how I can do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to use a straight mean:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Working.Overtime = mean(c(Q1, Q2, Q3), na.rm = TRUE))
```